# csrf issue from node js to django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, node.js

**I want to pass the csrftoken from node.js to django. I have this code in my server.js**

```
socket.on('unread global', function (data) { 
var values=querystring.stringify();

var options = {
  hostname:'localhost',
  port:'8000',
  path:'/chat/global_unread/',
  method:'POST',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': 'csrftoken=' + data.csrf,
    'Content-Length':values.length
}
}
```

**My data come from a jquery function that calls my server.js**

```
var datos = { // datos is the data that will be send to Node.js

        user: USER_PK_CHAT,
        csrf : window.CSRF_TOKEN

      };

  socket.emit('unread global', datos);
```

**But at the end I always get the same error in my console**

Reason given for failure:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when

For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies... so on
can sombody help me?

Comment: Most probably the token is incorrect. You need to inspect more detail on the initial request to retrieve the token.

Comment: Django and node.js almost certainly use different mechanisms for generating CSRF tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF middleware looks for the following COOKIE:

```
request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME]
```

And compare it to the POST csrfmiddlewaretoken.

So you have to make sure that the call to node sets the correct cookie name in:

```
'Cookie': 'csrftoken=' + data.csrf`
```

And also, that the POST includes a `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. It's safe to access the COOKIE in javascript and send it as the correct token, just make sure you use CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE. The better way is usually to let django put the token as an input field, and set the cookie separately.