# Is it possible to change the Django csrf token name and token header

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I am building a app using Angular and Django

by default, Django uses `X-CSRFToken` as the csrf header and `csrftoken` as the token name.

I Want to rename the header name to something `X-SOMENAME` and token as `sometokenName`,

I know with Angular we can change the default names with`$http.defaults`

Is it possible to change the token name on Django so that the generated token has `sometokenName` and the header Django looks to `X-SOMENAME`?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231619/csrf-issue-from-node-js-to-django/35232356#35232356

Comment: @AviahLaor, I think the answer by `GwynBleidD` is straight forward and painless. thank you

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For header name and cookie name you can change it using `CSRF_COOKIE_NAME` and `CSRF_HEADER_NAME`. Unfortunately, you can't change POST field that easy. You will have to modify `CsrfViewMiddleware` for that. But if you're using angular, you can use only headers and completely omit POST fields for that.

Comment: Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266828/how-to-add-csrf-token-to-angular-8-post-request-from-django-2-2 and help.